# How to print lines using find and sed in multiple files?

Tags: sed, find, xargs

I've many files in a directories structure. I want to extract some string (namely urls) by using a regexp, from those files.

I've tried this :

```
find . -path "*alder/ * / * .html" -print | xargs sed -n "/http:\/\/[^'\"]*/p" > urls.txt
```

... but it does not work as expected. The `find` part works ok, the `xargs` one, ok but the `sed` one, no. All I get in urls.txt is the concatenation of all files.

Comment: Your sed will print any line that has `http://` on it, the entire line, is that what you actually want?  If not, is `sed` a requirement, or would solutions that do not involve `sed` also be acceptable?

Comment: With its embedded spaces, the test `-path "*alder/ * / * .html"` looks suspicious.  What files are you really trying to find?

Answer (score 1):

Using your same `find` command, this will return the URLs that match the regex:

```
find . -path "*alder/ * / * .html"  -exec grep -oh "http://[^'\"]*" {} +
```

Unlike `find...-print | xargs command...`, this approach will work on files whose names contain whitespace or other difficult characters

The `-o` option to `grep` tells it to return only the matching part, not the line that the match is on.  `-h` tells it to omit printing of the file names from which the matches were found.

The `find` command in the OP only matches files whose names have spaces in the path.  Since I suspect that this is not what you want, here is an alternative form of the `find` command that finds all `.html` files at any depth under the subdirectories of the current directory whose names end in `alder`:

```
find *alder/ -name '*.html' -exec grep -oh "http://[^'\"]*" {} +
```

#### More robust approach

To guard against other kinds of bad `html` files, cas suggests letting whitespace or `>` also signal the end of a URL and also accepting `https` as well as `http`:

```
find . -path "*alder/ * / * .html"  -exec grep -oEh "https?://[^'\"[:space:]>]*" {} +
```

Comment: +1. Also, I'd add `[:blank:]` and a `>` to the negated character-class in grep, to cope with a few more varieties of (potentially broken) html.

Comment: @cas Thanks.  I added that to the answer.  (In keeping with your suggestion, I hope, I switched from `[:blank:]` to `[:space:]` so that `\r`, `\n`, `\v`, and `\f` would also signal the end of a URL.)

Comment: yeah, i initially thought of using `[:space:]` but newlines etc won't match anyway because `grep` only sees one line at a time....so changed it to `[:blank:]`.  BTW, you forgot the `>` in the char-class...to catch, e.g.  `<a href=http://unquoted.url/>`.  probably should use `https?:` instead of just `http:` too.  None of this will catch relative URLs, though.  Which is, of coursse, one of the many reasons why a HTML parser should be used instead of grep.

Comment: @cas Very good.  Answer updated.  (Although `space` seems worth keeping even if only because of the `\r` characters that DOS adds.)

Comment: true, i forgot about that.

Comment: But `-print0` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the quick answers. Sorry for the extra spaces in the path, but removing them turns the path into something odd when trying to post here.

I wanted to use sed for grep is really, really slow on more than 1.2 gB, 25,000 files.

I've found an answer. A first sed command to chop the files with "'= chars, and then a second sed command to print the lines. Here is it :

find . -path "*alder.com/ * / * .html" -print| xargs sed -r "s/[\"'=]/\n/g"| sed -n "/^http\s?:/p" > urls.txt