# Recursively find all files named "file.txt" and execute a sed command

Tags: shell-script, sed, find

The challenge of my task is that the `file.txt` can be in subfolder or in sub-sub folders. The general structure looks like this:

```
   folder
     |___subfolder
             |_____file.txt
     |
     |___subfolder
             |____subfolder
                      |_______file.txt
     etc
```

My previous code does not deal with the sub-sub folder and I am not sure how to add in this part (since some sub folder does not have any subsequent folders)

```
 for dir in ./*/ ; do
        if [ -d "$dir" ]; then 
           cd $d;
           for subdir in ./*/; do
               cd $subdir && $(sed command file.txt) && cd ..;
           done
           cd ..
        fi
done
```

I have also learned there's a one line method of using `find`, something like:

```
find . -name 'file.txt' | sed command file.txt
```

Apparently this one doesn't work as `find` only returns the dir to my `file.txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print lines using find and sed in multiple files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/289764/44760)

Answer (score 18):

Try:

```
find . -name 'file.txt' -exec sed command {} +
```

This finds all files named `file.txt` that in subdirectories of `.` and runs `sed command` against those files.

If you want `sed` to modify those files in place, then add the `-i` option.

Althought `-exec ... +` is now required by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) (hat tip: jordanm), some people may be using old versions of BSD `find` that do not support `+`.  If you have one of those, then use (hat tip: unxnut):

```
find . -name 'file.txt' -exec sed command {} \;
```

**More Secure Alternative**

If rapid changes are made to the directory structure, `-exec` can be subject to a race-condition.  For greater security, use `-execdir` (hat tip: unxnut):

```
find . -name 'file.txt' -execdir sed command {} +
```

Note that, if you have the current directory in your `PATH`, then `-execdir` will refuse to run.

Comment: @unxnut What was the reason for replacing `-exec sed command {} +` with the much less efficient `-exec sed command {} \;`?

Comment: Why is `+` more efficient than `\;`?  Isn't `\;` more portable?

Comment: @unxnut (a) Regarding portability, I think that that used to be true: old versions of BSD find did not support `+`.  But, I am not aware of any of those being still in general use.  (b) For efficiency, the use of `+` greatly reduces the number of `sed` processes that must be created.  `\;` creates one sed for every file.  `+` puts many files on the same sed command line, requiring only one invocation of sed for the whole group.

Comment: @unxnut For example, both [Mac OSX](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) and [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)) have finds which support `+`.

Comment: I checked again and you are right.  However, a better option for `exec` is `execdir`, preventing some race conditions.

Comment: @unxnut `+` is part of the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html)

Comment: @jordanm Very good.  I added that link to the answer.

Comment: @unxnut You are right that `-execdir` is more secure.  Answer updated.

Comment: I would suggest to use ``find -print0|xargs -0 sed 'some sed stuff' -i``, as ``find -exec`` spawns one process per file, while ``xargs`` uses one sed for all files, which is much faster if you have a lot of files.

Comment: @allo There have been some broken versions of `find` that behaved that way.  Unlike `-exec ... {} \;`, the form with a plus sign, `-exec ... {} +`, should put many file names on the same line just like `xargs` would.

Comment: @allo You can test to see if your `find` is broken by running something like: `find . -name '*.txt' -exec echo {} + | wc -l`.  This will output the number of times `echo` was executed.  That should be far far less than the actual number of `*.txt` in the path.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you know what that `sed` command is doing you want to run one `sed` per input file.
You can do this with either a `for` loop (if your shell supports recursive globbing) e.g. `zsh`, `ksh93`, `yash`, `bash` (`tcsh` and `fish` as well, but the loop syntax is different there).

```
shopt -s globstar        # bash
#set -o globstar         # ksh93
#set -o extended-glob    # yash

for f in **/file.txt; do [ -f "$f" ] && sed 'cmd' "$f"; done
```

or (as pointed out by other people) with `find`:

```
find . -type f -name 'file.txt' -exec sed 'cmd' {} \;
```

---

Now, one may wonder - why not "optimize" this and use `find`s `-exec` with `+`  or a `zsh`-ism like:

```
sed 'cmd' **/file.txt(.)
```

Sure, these would be more efficient as they invoke `sed` with multiple *file* operands but *that* may well the problem:
for the sake of simplicity, imagine you're trying to print only the 1st line of each file using the `sed` command `1q`<sup>1</sup> (without editing the file in-place<sup>2</sup>, maybe to redirect the combined output to another file or just to inspect it) so you would run either

```
find . -name 'file.txt' -exec sed '1q' {} +
```

or

```
sed '1q' **/file.txt(.)
```

however they will both fail to deliver because
*if multiple file operands are specified, the named files shall be read in the order specified and the concatenation shall be edited*
and as a result `sed` will only print the 1st line of input not the 1st line of each file<sup>3</sup>.
Now, `gnu sed` has the `-s` switch:

```
-s, --separate
        consider files as separate rather than as a single continuous long stream
```

that might come in handy sometimes but in this particular case (`1q`), it won't help.

---

<sup>1: if you don't like `1q` try `$d` which should delete the last line from each file</sup>
<sup>2: you might get away with `gnu sed` sometimes as `-i` implies `-s`, but definitely not when one of the `sed` commands is `q`</sup>
<sup>3: you might argue that this is because `q` quits - but the same would happen if you used `sed -n '1p'` - I only used `q` to emphasize 2:</sup>

Comment: Note a difference between `**/file` and `find`: the former will not descend into hidden directories.

Comment: Note a difference between `**/file; [[ -f ]]` and `find -type f`/`**/file(.)`: the former will include symlinks to directories. Also note that with `bash` prior to 4.3, `**` followed symlinks when descending the directories.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your file paths don't contain blanks, newlines, single quote, double quote or backslash characters:

```
find . -name 'file.txt' -type f | xargs sed command
```

Comment: @Rahul why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but a couple of reasons the downvoter might have thought: 1. no need to use `pipe-xargs`, as `find` has the `-exec` or `-execdir` actions and 2. if you use `pipe-xargs`, at least do it in a way that won't fail with files with spaces or newlines in its name: `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 sed ...` (I don't know about the portability of this).

Comment: Given my reputation is too low to comment on the solution proposed by @John1024 I'll do it here, shouldn't that solution include the -type f to avoid processing any directories with the name 'file.txt', which was the main reason for my answer? the use of xargs was just to show another way...